Markdown Not Displaying Command Prompt's Python Command
I have a note taking web app that receives your notes in markdown and present them nicely in html. The address is immorta.netlify.app. I have been taking notes without a problem in the platform for four months now, but yesterday, while writing this line of code python -m jupyterlab as part of my notes, the platform threw the following error:
immorta.netlify.app/:1  Access to fetch at 'https://immorta.onrender.com/updateNote/66da0aeb3c86333dd2e3a131' from origin 'https://immorta.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Everything seems to work fine if I write the code snippet as normal text. What could be the cause of the problem? Remember, the platform had been taking Python code before without a problem, but I have to admit, this is the first time I've written executable cmd code in it.
